# SyntaxError in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Why it is giving this error?
[Please see the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XJRV.png%60)

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :category %><br />
    <%= f.select :category_id, Category.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {:include_blank => 'Select One'} class:'form-control' %><br /> <br />
</div>
```

Comment: Don't attach images, quote text.

Comment: You're missing a comma.

Comment: Please have a look at the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a comma before class

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :category %><br />
    <%= f.select :category_id, Category.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {:include_blank => 'Select One'}, class:'form-control' %><br /> <br />
</div>
```